# Bash script to automate Open VPN

Tags: bash, ssh, openvpn

so what I'm trying to do is to write a Bash script that will ssh into a server and generate new user credentials. However, it won't create the new user keys, but it can tell you if a user already exists.

```
echo "You entered $NAME. Is this correct?(y/n) "
read AN

while [ "$AN" != "y" ]
do
    echo "Enter the correct user name: "
    read NAME
    echo "You entered $NAME. Is this correct(y/n)? "
    read AN
done

ssh -t x@0.0.0.0 <<EOF

if [ ! -e /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/"$NAME.crt" ]
then
    cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
    source vars
    ./pkitool "$NAME"
else
    echo "File already exists!"
fi

exit
EOF
scp x@0.0.0.0:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/$NAME.crt .
```

This code can generate new user keys, but when I add the if block, it then will no longer create new keys for some reason. Anybody have any ideas why the if block doesn't properly work?

EDIT: I solved it

Comment: Do you mean while loop not if loop?

Comment: @Tom Cammann The `while` loop works fine for me, maybe he means the `if` *block*

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't properly work"? What are the symptoms / outputs?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm asking about the why the if loop doesn't work properly.

Comment: @sampson-chen the output for a new user, call them billy would be scp: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/billy.crt: No such file or directory

It works just fine for existing users though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I accidentally moved ca.crt into a different folder. This explains why new user keys couldn't be made.

I appreciate the help, sorry for the newbie mistake.